# Vue: What is the cleanest way to select a component via CSS?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a `bar` component. It is used like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <!-- stuff -->
    <bar></bar>
    <!-- stuff -->
    <!-- stuff -->
    <!-- stuff -->
    <bar></bar>
    <!-- stuff -->
    <bar></bar>
    <!-- stuff -->  
  </div>
</template>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
  @media (max-width: 1300px) {
    // this selector doesn't work, but it would be nice if it did
    bar {
      display: none;
    }
  }
</style>
```

I would like to hide the bar elements when the screen is 1300px or narrower. It would be nice if there was a `bar` element selector, just like there are `p` and `h1` element selectors. However, there doesn't seem to be, and I have to add `class="bar"` in order to select them.

My question is if there is a cleaner way to select the `bar` elements.

It wouldn't be good to add the CSS code inside of the `bar` component because when the `bar`s are used inside of other components, I *don't* want to hide them at all.

Comment: For what purpose?

Comment: @Bert I'm looking to add a CSS rule to the component (in this case, `display: none;` when the screen is under 1300px). As for why I am looking for something other than `class="bar"`, I feel that my code would be cleaner if I could avoid it. Just like how you would use an `li` selector rather than adding `class="li"` and a `.li` selector if you wanted to select all list items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A class seems to be the best way to go. Put it on the root element of the component if you want it to be universal for the component, or only on the component tag if you want it to be specific to that use.

Also, there is no reason you couldn't use a custom tag as the root element of your component; as long as the tag didn't map to a component, it would be left in the DOM, and you could use it for CSS selection. I don't recommend it, though, as I don't think this use case is a good reason for introducing a new tag.

If your component template looked like this, for example:

```
<template>
  <bar-container>
    Hi there
  </bar-container>
</template>
```

and you had no `bar-container` component defined, you would be able to use CSS to select `bar-container`, which would be the container element for every `bar` component. But it's just as easy to use `<div class="bar-container">` instead.

Comment: I edited the question to be more clear. I am using vue-loader and scoped CSS, but I am looking to select the `bar` from a (specific) parent component, not from within the bar component.

Comment: I've removed the first line of my answer; the rest still applies.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about the custom tag thing. Would you mind elaborating on that? Also, even if I had a custom tag that I could select for with CSS, how would it help me select the `<bar>`s?

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks for the explanation and updates. I had tried `<div class="bar-container">`. I assumed the reason why it wasn't working for me was something related to Vue, but now I realize that it was just a CSS specificity error on my part. I agree that `<div class="bar-container">` is just as easy as `<bar-container>`, and would be the best solution. My original issue was with `<bar class="bar">` being used many times; with _using_ the component. With `<div class="bar-container">` in the _template_ of the component, I'd only be adding a class once, which I think is fine.

Comment: This is not a solution, this is a hack, and a very bad practice one at that.

Comment: @Spooky You should probably say what "this" refers to and how it's bad.

Comment: @spooky What a strange response. Ok, you didn't want to communicate anything but your contempt for an answer. But I'm the one who needs to brush up on politeness. Sure.

Answer (score 0):

After better understanding the problem at hand, would this work?

```
<div class="someClass">
    <bar v-bind:width="draw.probability" type="draw" ref="myComponent"></bar>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm looking to select the component with CSS, not JavaScript. Also, `ref="myComponent"` adds (essentially) just as much extra code as `class="bar"`.

Comment: yea, but its the "vue" way to do it.

Comment: are you looking to use jquery to get access to a vue component?

Comment: I'm looking to add a CSS rule to the component (in this case, `display: none;`when the screen is under 1300px).

Comment: inside of that component you could just wrap everything in a <div> and then use css rule on that div inside the component

Comment: The `bar`s are interspersed, not in sequence like a bunch of list elements. Otherwise, I like the container approach.