# How to define router-link content color in vue.js

Tags: css, vue.js

In my project, I use vue.js of App.vue.

I have defined route-link for goods,ratings,and seller.

And I want to set color of them in style module.

Here is template module of App.vue:

```
<template>
<div id="app">
 <v-header></v-header>
 <div class="tab">
<div class="tab-item">
  <router-link to='/'>goods</router-link>
</div>
<div class="tab-item">
  <router-link to='/rating'>ratings</router-link>
</div>
<div class="tab-item">
  <router-link to='/seller'>seller</router-link>
</div>
</div>
<router-view></router-view>
</div>
</template>
```

Here is style modual of App.vue.

```
<style lang="stylus" rel="stylesheet/stylus">
 #app
  .tab
    display: flex
    width: 100%
    height: 40px
    line-heigh: 40px
    .tab-item
      flex: 1
      text-align: center
     & > router-link
      display: block
      color: rgb(240, 20, 20)
 </style>
```

But i found these definition did not work:

```
& > router-link
      display: block
      color: rgb(240, 20, 20)
```

In chrome's Elements, I found that:

```
<route-link to='/'>goods</router-link>
```

had been changed to

```
<a href="#/" class="router-link-exact-active router-link-active">goods</a>
```

When I had tested that a label instead of route-link, it was not OK all the same, like

```
& > a
 display: block
 color: rgb(240, 20, 20)
```

I don't know why, who can give me a help?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't select a custom Vue.js component using the css selector notation. You can add a class to your router-links and select them using that class name. It's not as convenient as being able to select by element type, but it will work. For example, turn this `<router-link to='/seller'>seller</router-link>` into this `<router-link to='/seller' class="routerlink">seller</router-link>`. Then in your css, turn this:

```
& > router-link
  display: block
  color: rgb(240, 20, 20)
```

Into this:

```
& > .routerlink
  display: block
  color: rgb(240, 20, 20)
```

See this question for more information: [Vue: What is the cleanest way to select a component via CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48287567/vue-what-is-the-cleanest-way-to-select-a-component-via-css)

Comment: I have tested as you said. But it also does not work.

Comment: Can you post a minimal, complete, verifiable example (just enough code so that if I run it, I get the same problem or error you do?) That way I can try to see what's going on. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Put This Style On component:

```
<v-btn flat class="font-weight-bolder text-white" to="/contact">

.v-toolbar__items .v-btn:not(.v-btn--floating):not(.v-btn--icon),
.v-toolbar__items .v-menu,
.v-toolbar__items .v-menu__activator {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your can set a default tag :

```
<router-link :to="/path" exact tag="div"> </router-link>`
```

In your style section you car aslo constum the tag by:

```
.router-link-exact-active{ // your style herer }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use a {your css style} since it will be converted to an anchor, that worked for me.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34419077)